# Batch command to run bat file automatically upon computer log in

Tags: windows, authentication, automation, dos, batch-processing

Is there any batch command/script which run a batch file automatically upon computer log in? I don't want to use task scheduler or any programs because you still need to set it automatically. I want the batch file to run automatically without any manual setup.

Answer (score 0):

Simply copy the batch file into your startup folder.  Which will usually be somewhere like 
C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup

Not sure if that constitutes "manual" setup, but any method will require to setup something once.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating an autoexec.bat in the root directory of your C: drive. It should run automatically each time the PC boots

http://www.computerhope.com/ac.htm